# How to add a signature above post content in Blogspot?

Tags: google-workspace, blogger, html

I have searched this in google, but only finds how to add signature below the post content.
I want it to appear on the post page and not on the home page. So how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using conditional tags like this, ff you insert signature inside template

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isPost'>
      <!-- your signature -->
</b:if>
```

If you use css only to add signature, try add `.item-view` selector like this:

```
.item-view .entry-content:after {
  content:url(your url);
 }
```